# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void updatechildrec(List<Work_detail__c>, Map<Id,Work_detail__c>) from the type updatechidrecdsdup

Tags: apex, lightning-development

```
trigger udpatewordetailrec on Work_detail__c (before update) 
{
     updatechidrecdsdup.updatechildrec(Trigger.New,Trigger.oldMap);
}


public class updatechidrecdsdup {
public static void updatechildrec(List<Work_order__c> workordlist,Map<id,Work_order__c> mapworkid)
 {
      Boolean partsordnew,partsordold;
      Boolean workdetailnew,workdetaiold;

     List<Work_order__c> workordlist1= new List<Work_order__c>();
     Set<Id> workid =new Set<Id>();//Declaring ID field to Work order
     Map<id,Work_order__c>  workidmap=new Map<id,Work_order__c>();//retriving all work order ids and records to map

     for(Work_order__c curwork:workordlist)
     {
            workid.add(curwork.Id);
            workidmap.put(curwork.Id, curwork);
            workdetailnew=workidmap.get(curwork.Id).status__c.contains('Inprogress');
            workdetaiold=curwork.status__c.contains('Accepted');
            workordlist1.add(curwork);

     }
     List<Parts_order__c> partsorder = new List<Parts_order__c>();//creating parts order list
     Set<Id> partsordid =new Set<Id>();//creating id
     Map<id,Parts_order__c> partsmapid= new Map<id,Parts_order__c>();

         for(Parts_order__c partsord: [select Id,name,SerialNumber__c from Parts_order__c where PartsOrderName__c=:workid])
         {
             partsordid.add(partsord.Id);
             partsmapid.put(partsord.Id, partsord);
             partsorder.add(partsord);
         }

           List<Parts_Order_List__c> partsordlist =new List<Parts_Order_List__c>();
              Set<Id> partsordlistid =new Set<Id>();
           Map<id,Parts_Order_List__c> partoridmap;
           for(Parts_Order_List__c partordid:[select id,name,List_Status__c,update_email_list__c    from Parts_Order_List__c where PartsorderlistName__c =:partsordid])
          {

                    partsordnew=partoridmap.get(partordid.Id).List_status__c.contains('open');
                    partsordold=partordid.List_status__c.contains('completed');
                   partsordlistid.add(partordid.Id);
                   partoridmap.put(partordid.Id, partordid);
                   partsordlist.add(partordid);

          }

         Map<id,work_detail__c>  workidmap1=new Map<id,work_detail__c>();
         Set<Id> workdetailid =new Set<Id>();
         for(work_detail__c workdetrec: [select id,name,update_work_list__c,SerialNumber__c from work_detail__c where ChildworkdetailName__c =:partsordlistid])
         {
              workdetailid.add(workdetrec.Id);
             workidmap1.put(workdetrec.Id, workdetrec);
             if(partsordnew==true && partsordold==true)
                     {
                          if(workdetailnew==true && workdetaiold==true)
                          {
                              workdetrec.update_parts_email_list__c=partoridmap.get(workdetrec.ChildworkdetailName__c).update_email_list__c;

                          }
                     }
         }         
 }
}
```

Comment: what exactly the issue you are facing?

Comment: trigger udpatewordetailrec on Work_detail__c (before update) 
{
     updatechidrecdsdup.updatechildrec(Trigger.New,Trigger.oldMap);
}  I wrote trigger for this it is displaying Error:Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void updatechildrec(List<Work_detail__c>, Map<Id,Work_detail__c>) from the type updatechidrecdsdup

Comment: i edited code by placing Trigger and What type of issue i am facing. plz check it once.

Comment: issue is you are passing list of Work_detail__c  instead of Work_order__c.

Comment: Trigger.New,Trigger.oldMap contains list<Work_detail__c > and Map<id,Work_detail__c > and your helper method has the prototype updatechildrec(List<Work_order__c> workordlist,Map<id,Work_order__c> mapworkid).

Comment: Thanks allot Dude... I confused wrote on another object..

Answer (score 1):

`Trigger.New,Trigger.oldMap` contains `list<Work_detail__c >` and `Map<id,Work_detail__c >` and your helper method has the prototype `updatechildrec(List<Work_order__c> workordlist,Map<id,Work_order__c> mapworkid)`.
try something like this,

```
public static void updatechildrec(List<Work_detail__c> workordlist,Map<id,Work_detail__c> mapworkid)
 {
    Set<Id> workord = new Set<Id>();
    for(Work_detail__c w: workordlist)
        workord.add(w.Work_order__c);
    Map<id,Work_order__c> mapworkid = (Map<id, Work_order__c>) [ query for Work_order__c id in :workord ];

    // your code
}
```